# How to perform hourly incremental extracts from an oracle datasource using last_mod_dt (timestamp) in Airflow?

Tags: airflow, etl, data-extraction, incremental-load

Need to do hourly table refresh/loads using Airflow/Python from an oracle datasource using last_modified_dt timestamp column.

In Airflow there's airflow.models.taskinstance API which exposes data from task_instance metadata table and which has following fields (shown with sample data), assuming the dag/tasks first execution date/time was 1/1/2020 05:00 :-

```
task_id, dag_id, execution_datetime (of dag), start_date, end_date, duration, state, ....
task_a, oracle, 1/1/2020 05:00:00, 1/1/2020 05:00:00, 1/1/2020 05:05:00, 0.5, success, ....
task_b, oracle, 1/1/2020 05:00:00, 1/1/2020 05:01:00, 1/1/2020 05:04:00, 0.3, success, ....
task_c, oracle, 1/1/202005:00:00, 1/1/2020 05:02:00, 1/1/2020 05:06:00, 0.4, success, ....
```

So, am thinking of using this task_instance metadata table or API to get the previous start datetime of each task and its state (success) and use that in a condition like below:

So, when running after an hour at 1/1/2020 06:00:00 :-

```
select * from table_a where last_mod_dttm > prev(start_datetime of task_id=task_a) and state = sucesss;
select * from table_b where last_mod_dttm > prev(start_datetime of task_id=task_b) and state = sucesss;
select * from table_c where last_mod_dttm > prev(start_datetime of task_id=task_c) and state = sucesss;
```

Is this approach right ? If yes, then querying directly airflow metadata task_instance table every time to get the previous or max(start_datetime) of a task(s) would have any performance implications?  If yes, then how do we get the previous start_datetime and "success" state of a task via airflow.models.taskinstance API (https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/airflow/models/taskinstance/index.html)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it's important to understand how `execution_date` works, see [Scheduler Doc](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html):

> The scheduler won’t trigger your tasks until the period it covers has
> ended e.g., A job with schedule_interval set as @daily runs after the
> day has ended. This technique makes sure that whatever data is
> required for that period is fully available before the dag is
> executed. **In the UI, it appears as if Airflow is running your tasks a
> day late.**
>
> If you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run with
> execution_date 2019-11-21 triggers soon after 2019-11-21T23:59.
>
> **Let’s Repeat That, the scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval
> AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.**

This means by referencing `execution_date` you get exactly the time when the last run was triggered.

Regarding the query, I wouldn't query the database to get the last execution date but rather use Macros that come out of the box with Airflow - [see this reference](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros-ref.html):

You should be able to just use `{{ execution_date }}` in your query and Airflow should replace it when the DAG run is triggered.

Comment: Thanks @Philipp Johannis, if your this statement is correct:- "This means by referencing execution_date you get exactly the time when the last run was triggered." - then I think it would solve my purpose if I am scheduling to run it every 1 hour, I always want to get the last execution date (i.e. an hour before). Although, for the first initial run would it consider the execution date as current date/time ?

Comment: So I would work with something like `where last_mod_dttm between '{{ execution_date }}' and '{{ next_execution_date }}'` - then it shouldn't matter if you run daily, hourly or in whatever interval. You may need to put some cast in the sql to convert the template to a timestamp. 
I have a separate DAG to do a full load (schedule `@once`) and one DAG for incremental refreshes.

Comment: prev_execution_date_success = "{{ prev_execution_date_success.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }}"
next_execution_date = "{{ next_execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }}" sql = 'SELECT * FROM '+str(table)+' WHERE LAST_MODIFIED_DATE BETWEEN '+ "'{}'".format(prev_execution_date_success) + ' AND ' + "'{}'".format(next_execution_date) + ';' .  SQL generated= SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE DATE_LAST_MODIFIED BETWEEN '2020-10-22 13:01:40' AND '2020-10-22 16:42:23'; However, giving error:- **Error: must be str, not int.**  The same SQL output runs fine in source database.

Comment: Is the error thrown when triggering the sql statement or already before? Because `Error: must be str, not int` is a python error message and not an error message from a database.

Comment: There was a missing str() in my code which I fixed it. However, now am getting error:- 'NoneType object' has no attribute 'strftime'. Actually, to elaborate - I have a dag with lets say 3 tasks for each table on which I want to implement hourly incremental loads. Therefore, I need to check the task instance of each table (task) from the previous dag run and get the previous execution date and success state (i.e. prev_execution_date_success) . Also, if its executing for the first time then it should default previous_execution_date_success to current utc time.  Here's how I have defined it:

Comment: curr_exec_time = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
prev_execution_date_success = "{{ prev_execution_date_success.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }}"
prev_execution_date_success = curr_exec_time if prev_execution_date_success is None else prev_execution_date_success
next_execution_date = "{{ next_execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }}" ...... Not sure what I am doing wrong here, if running manually for first time and/or manually setting the previous dag & its tasks state to success  - it runs fine. But, after an hour during next schedule- it fails with above error.

Comment: Now also started getting below Exception when it is automated scheduled to run every 1 hour: Executor reports task instance finished (failed) although the task says its queued. Was the task killed externally?

Comment: I assume `prev_execution_date_success = "{{ prev_execution_date_success.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }}"` triggers `'NoneType object' has no attribute 'strftime'.` Because for the first DAG Run it should be None.

Comment: Right, but it was still giving me same error even after I had condition that if prev_exec_date_success is none then take previous_hr (from curr_date/time) as execution date. So, I had to manually set it to "success" for the first time run and then it started working. May be am doing something wrong and have to re-look. Now it is getting successful executions after every hour, but every time getting this error, after successful execution:-  **Try 0 out of 1
Exception:
Executor reports task instance finished (failed) although the task says its queued. Was the task killed externally?**